# jQuery CSS change on X seconds - Is it possible to be different for the first transition?

Tags: jquery, css

I have the following code which adds and removes a class every 2000 milliseconds:

http://jsfiddle.net/Kh2fz/1/

```
var $elements = $('#fp-slides div'); 
var total_elements = $elements.length;
var element_with_class = 0;
window.setInterval( function () {
  $elements.eq(element_with_class).removeClass('current');
  element_with_class += 1;
  if ( element_with_class === total_elements )
  {
      element_with_class = 0;
  }
  $elements.eq(element_with_class).addClass('current');  
}, 2000 );
```

I'm wondering if it is possible to change it so that the first effect is 1500 and then every change after that is then 2000.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `setTimeout for the fist time and then run`setInterval`:

```
var $elements = $('#fp-slides div'); 

var total_elements = $elements.length;
var element_with_class = 0;

var handler = function () {

  $elements.eq(element_with_class).removeClass('current');

  element_with_class += 1;

  if ( element_with_class === total_elements )
  {
      element_with_class = 0;
  }

  $elements.eq(element_with_class).addClass('current'); 
};

window.setTimeOut( function() { 
    handler(), 
    window.setInterval(handler, 2000); 
}, 1500);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Kh2fz/3/

Comment: I'm getting the error: "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object DOMWindow] has no method 'setTimeOut'"

Comment: `setTimeout` not `setTimeOut` :)

Answer (score 3):

Just use a setTimeout for this.

```
function animateStuff() {
    $elements.eq(element_with_class).removeClass('current');
    element_with_class += 1;
    if ( element_with_class === total_elements )
    {
      element_with_class = 0;
    }
    $elements.eq(element_with_class).addClass('current'); 
    setTimeout(animateStuff, 2000); 
}
setTimeout(animateStuff, 1500 );
```

Also, doing animations in this way is generally less jittery because you can't always rely on setInterval being exactly X milliseconds.  The timing can be really quite inaccurate across varying devices.  This way you ensure that the next animation is run when the previous has completed.  Setinterval certainly has its place, just not with timing critical functions.

Answer (score 0):

what you could do:

```
var $elements = $('#fp-slides div'); 
var total_elements = $elements.length;
var element_with_class = 0;

function callMeEveryXSeconds() {
  $elements.eq(element_with_class).removeClass('current');
  element_with_class += 1;
  if ( element_with_class === total_elements )
  {
      element_with_class = 0;
  }
  $elements.eq(element_with_class).addClass('current'); 
  // this is called second, third, fourth, etc. time 
  setTimeout( "callMeEveryXSeconds();", 2000 );
};
// this is called first
setTimeout( "callMeEveryXSeconds();", 1500 );
```